# Pyspark : Add, substract hour/minute/second from int column to another timestamp column

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this pyspark dataframe :

```
df
id, duration, ts_col
'abc', 3, 2023-03-01 22:00:00
...
```

I want to create 2 new columns, ts_before and ts_after which are respectively the result of `ts_col` minus `duration` and plus `duration`.
The expected result would be:

```
df2
id, duration, ts_col, ts_before, ts_after
'abc', 3, 2023-03-01 22:00:00, 2023-03-01 19:00:00, 2023-03-02 01:00:00
```

I know how to add a specific amount to my ts_col with `df2 = df.withColumn("ts_before", df.ts_col- F.expr(f"INTERVAL 3 HOUR"))` but if I input `duration` instead of `3` it throws an error. What am I missing ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `make_interval` function.

**`Exmaple:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df =spark.createDataFrame([('abc','3','2023-03-01 22:00:00',)],['id','duration','ts_col']).withColumn("ts_col",to_timestamp(col("ts_col")))
df.withColumn("ts_before",col("ts_col")+expr("make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, -duration, 0, 0)")).\
  withColumn("ts_after",col("ts_col")+expr("make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, duration, 0, 0)")).show(10,False)
#+---+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|id |duration|ts_col             |ts_before          |ts_after           |
#+---+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|abc|3       |2023-03-01 22:00:00|2023-03-01 19:00:00|2023-03-02 01:00:00|
#+---+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

---

**`Another way:`**

```
df.withColumn("ts_before", to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(col("ts_col")) +  col("duration")*3600)).\
  withColumn("ts_after", to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(col("ts_col")) -  col("duration")*3600)).\
    show(10,False)
#+---+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|id |duration|ts_col             |ts_before          |ts_after           |
#+---+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
#|abc|3       |2023-03-01 22:00:00|2023-03-02 01:00:00|2023-03-01 19:00:00|
#+---+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```